# ext.net / How to run server-side method on Row Click in GridPanel?

Tags: .net, click, row, ext.net

Hey,
messing about with ext.net and running into a few minor issues.

Im trying to run a server-side method when a user clicks on a row in a GridPanel. From the examples I read on the Internet it should be straight forward, but it is not working.

So, I have a GridPanel (in MyTest.aspx)

```
<ext:GridPanel ... >
   ...
   <Listeners>
       <RowClick Handler="SetCustomer"/>
   </Listeners>
```

and then the server-side method (in MyTest.aspx.cs)

```
    [DirectMethod]
    public void SetCustomer()
    {
        uint customerId = 0;
        // does nothing
    }
```

The SetCustomer is not executed, but the listener is working. I check this by instead of

```
<RowClick Handler="SetCustomer"/>
```

I do

```
<RowClick Handler="alert('test')"/>
```

and that works. So, any ideas would be appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RowClick Handler="Ext.net.DirectMethods.SetCustomer();"/>
```

See http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectMethods/Overview/

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, I just thought that was a namespace in my actual project, and thus I didnt use it... hehe.

Comment: Hi is it possible to add two RowClick Handlers ?